# Starting Remix project with netlify but got this error : Unexpected Server Error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, netlify, remix.run

I just started a new project with remix and netlify, it works in production but when I use npm run dev and go to localhost:3000 I get this :

```
Unexpected Server Error

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

which is weird cause it works in production and all I have done for now is following the README file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just forgot to run the posinstall script, it was not in the readme but in the documentation

```
npm run postinstall
```